# Change text based on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to write some C# that will detect a piece of a URL and change some text based on the URL found on Page Load.

Essentially, I want this to happen:

1. URL is detected as ending with ".us || .com" OR ".ca"
2. Change the text of an `<h1>` to say "United States" or "Canada" based on the URL found.

My C# experience with this sort of code is almost 0, so I don't have any code to show, because I don't know where to start. Can anyone help me get in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties%28v=vs.90%29) class and view the `Host` property to see if it contains `.us`, `.com`, or `.ca` with a simple string `EndsWith` operation.

Please keep in mind that when constructing the `Uri` class, you must pass in a valid URI.

Answer (score 2):

This question might help you in the right direction: [Top level domain from URL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643227/top-level-domain-from-url-in-c-sharp)

Then all you have to do is find the extension, wrap it up in a `switch` statement or something and wo what you want!

Answer (score 1):

If you are inpecting strings that match certain conditions then I would take a look at Regular Expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using JQuery too  http://jsfiddle.net/tEqwb/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if($(pathname +"*.us") || $(pathname +"*.com") || $(pathname +"*.ca"))
    {
      $("#theH1").text("United States");
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

if (ss.Contains(".us"))
            {
                //code for changing name to US
            }
            else if (ss.Contains(".ca"))
            {
                //code for changing name to canada
            }