# Regular expression to find a string included between two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am really bad at regex and would to to parse an email address using c#.

If my input is `user@domain.me.com`, what regex would I use to extract just the "domain" part? There can be multiple domains that are of different length.

Comment: so, you want the text between the `@` and the following `.`?

Comment: you can do this several ways that do not require `RegEx` for example are you familiar with `IndexOf()` method or `Split()` method..?

Comment: yes, the text between @ and the following .

Comment: I haven't use either methods. But I will look into those also.

Comment: `Raj` here are some other good examples to look at as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473838/get-domain-name-of-a-url-in-c-sharp-net also `GOOGLE.COM` is your best friend use it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not trivial to parse an email with a regex, because the rules for a valid email are complex; fortunately, you don't need to: you can use the [`MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/yh392kbs.aspx) class instead.

```
var address = new MailAddress("user@domain.me.com");
string domain = address.Host.Split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive look-behind to find the `@`, then grab text till a `.`:

`(?<=@)[^\.]+`

in code you could use:

```
var str = "user@domain.me.com";
var domain = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=@)[^\.]+").Groups[0].ToString();
```

you'll want to check your matches to ensure a match was found, I assume.