# How to correctly enable CORS for a subdomain in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to serve my assets on a subdomain instated of the same domain. So when my main domain is `https://localhost:44111/` the assets URL would be something like `https://assets.localhost:44111/css/style.css`

The `style.css` file makes a request to include a custom font `my_custom_font.eot` like so

```
@font-face {
    ....
    src: url('/css/fonts/my_custom_font.eot?123');
}
```

When I include the `style.css` file which is located on the assets subdomain, I get the following error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://assets.localhost:44111/css/fonts/my_custom_font.eot?123. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

To make sure I am clear, both `style.css` and `my_custom_font.eot` are located on the same domain `assets.localhost:44111`. The request to include `style.css` works with no issues. But, when `style.css` makes a request to include the `my_custom_font.eot` the request is prohibited.

I tried to follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to enable CORS. I added the following code to the `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSubDomainTraffic",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://assets.localhost:44111")
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

Then in the `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method I added the following

```
app.UseCors("AllowSubDomainTraffic");
```

However, I am still receiving the `CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing` error in the console of the browser.

This is how I respond to the subdomains in my app

```
app.MapWhen(context => {
    return context.Request.Host.Value.StartsWith("assets.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
} (appBuilder) =>
{
    appBuilder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("C:/assets"),
    });
});
```

How can I correctly enable CORS for a subdomain?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877652/configure-cors-to-allow-all-subdomains-using-asp-net-core-asp-net-5-mvc6-vnex

Comment: @chakeda I added `.SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()` to the chain of methods and then called `Build()` at the end, not still same issue. The documentation does not suggest to call  `Build()`  at the end. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WithOrigins(string[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withorigins?view=aspnetcore-3.0) takes an param of strings (array of string, string[]).  This allows you to do:

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44111", "https://assets.localhost:44111")
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowAnyMethod();
```

**note:** don't forget that cors urls cannot end in `/`