# CORS Issue in not allowing main domain in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using the below code in ASP.NET Core

```
         services.AddCors(policy => policy.AddPolicy(Constant.CorsPolicy, builder =>
        {
            var allowedDomain = configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowedDomains").Split(",");

            services.AddCors(policy => policy.AddPolicy(Constant.CorsPolicy, builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(allowedDomain)
                       .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();

            }));
        }));
```

to allow all subdomain and main domain, what this code does that it allow all subdomain, but it does not allow the main domain, I am reading values from configurations.

"AllowedDomains": "https://*.test.dk, http://*.test.dk, http://test.dk"

The following api is not allowed when its hit:

```
https://api.test.dk/api/v1/Product/Search
```

Comment: Are you doing `app.UseCors()` on your `Configure()` method at Startup?

Comment: Also your allowed domains configuration must have the wildcard syntax like "https://*.test.dk"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure cors to allow all subdomains using ASP.NET Core (Asp.net 5, MVC6, VNext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877652/configure-cors-to-allow-all-subdomains-using-asp-net-core-asp-net-5-mvc6-vnex)

Comment: Also on a side note, CORS allows your Webpage sitting on domain A to make a request to an API sitting on  domain B, when you say "the following api is not allowed" something makes me think you're trying API to API communication where CORS should not be an issue.

Comment: @PabloRecalde I am using app.UseCors(Constant.CorsPolicy);

Comment: @PabloRecalde in configuration its saved like this https://*.test.dk, http://*.test.dk, http://.test.dk

Comment: **First**, you should follow steps of [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .  **Then**,  [Test Cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#test-cors). When it works with a domain you set, then consider the subdomain  setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the CORS and write like this:

Within your ConfigureServices method

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddCors();
 }
```

And within your Configure method

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {

        app.UseCors(options =>
       options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod());
 }
```

Comment: "AllowedWildDomains": "https://*.test.dk"
"AllowedDomains": "http://test.dk"

options.AddPolicy(Constant.CorsWildPolicy,builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(allowedWildDomain)
                            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains().AllowAnyMethod() .AllowAnyHeader(); });

                options.AddPolicy(Constant.CorsPolicy,builder =>
                    { builder.WithOrigins(allowedDomain) .AllowAnyMethod() .AllowAnyHeader(); });

I have added two separate policies one for wildCard and other for domains. @noobprogrammer

Comment: @nooprogrammer I have added two policies 

app.UseCors(Constant.CorsPolicy);
app.UseCors(Constant.CorsWildPolicy);

Comment: My question is that How can i check if the front end application can correctly hit to my API?