# IdentityServer4 redirect callback cors error

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

in my `identityserver4` redirect callback i get cors error.
i enabled cors policy, and used `identityserver4` defaultcors class with `AllowAll` to true.
and i have my domain name in `AllowedCorsOrigins` in client config.
i tried any way and all articles but it always give cors error.
but if i try to make ajax request in that callback page it dont give me cors error to same page.
i cant understand it.

i have `http://ids.example.com`
and i have `http://example.com`

i there anything i can do to solve it. and this configuration works perfect in localhost.

Ids Config:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(container =>
{
    var logger = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
    return new DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
    {
        AllowAll = true
    };
});
```

Client Config:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "js.admin.prod",
    ClientName = "Instrumententafel",
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    RequireConsent = false,

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
    // AccessTokenLifetime = 299,
    RequirePkce = true,
    AllowPlainTextPkce = false,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,

    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://example.com",
        "http://example.com/logincb.html",
        "http://example.com/silent-renew.html"
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://example.com/",
        "http://example.com"
    },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
    {
        "http://example.com"
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "phone",
        "role",
        "api1.full"
    }
}
```

logincb.html:

```
<script src="./oidc-client.js"></script>
<script crossorigin>
  var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({
    response_mode: "query",
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
  })
    .signinRedirectCallback()
    .then(function(user) {
      console.log("signin response success", user);
      window.location.href = "/";
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
</script>
```

and the error is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ids.example.com/connect/token' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
logincb.html?code=396EA4E3D60DFF3620FAB600F3F0DB8AC7DC5CC7922341A3F8E7A3E973E10705&scope=openid profile email phone role offline_access api1.full&state=7fc1f62c72034eddab48a1cac1d261f2&session_state=rQ_HS6gus4BkM7tmL_xgJbWwLhm83nMbks1NCQYymBo.CC889AAAE84EAA20ABD2DFD643BB7797:22 Error: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onerror (JsonService.js:179)
```

Comment: Please, provide your IS4 conguration and the exact error.

Comment: @PWND hi i added IS4 config. and the fun thing is that only the token endpoint dont have allow cors origin header on response.

Comment: as I can propose, just add your subdomain (http://ids.example.com/) to necessary properties of the client like AllowedCorsOrigins, RedirectUris and PostLogoutRedirectUris.

Comment: @PWND in the logincb.html you mean i think?

Comment: No, into dotnet part.
I meant your Client Config part of the code above

Comment: @PWND didnt do the trick :D im actually lost.

Comment: I've also faced with the same error earlier, but difficult to predict what's happening without debugging) Try to update your global CORS as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877652/configure-cors-to-allow-all-subdomains-using-asp-net-core-asp-net-5-mvc6-vnex