# Strip protocol and subdomain from a URL

Tags: c#, url

I use the following code to remove `http://` and `www.` or `dev.` from a URL:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(this.Referrer);
    if (uri != null )
        return uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Replace("http://dev.", "").Replace("http://www.", "").Replace("http://", "");
    else
        return null;
```

I don't like that I'm relying on the `.Replace()` function.  I had a bug for quite a while until I realized that the `this.Referrer` didn't have the subdomain.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643227/top-level-domain-from-url-in-c-sharp

Comment: It's similar but not really applicable.

Comment: Surely the question is also not well phrased as even so called top level domains are all still sub-domains of the root domain `.(empty string)`. Doing it reliably would require having a list of the top level domains and then just taking one domain level below that.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4983072/188246 (You will have to change the pastebin a bit to work for you)

Comment: A hardcoded list...I'd advise against this, it's a big code smell and unnecessarily bloated.

Comment: How do you tell if something is a domain and not a tld then? For example, any `co.uk` tld.

Comment: I've updated my regex to be less greedy.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a hard coded list, feel free to fetch the top level domains from the IANA - http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: Still think it may be a little overkill considering what's been asked.  If OP was asking about URLs with many sub domains, then possibly regex wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: The only things I personally need to account for are `http://www.`, `http://` and `http://dev.`

Comment: Great! In that case we should act on the YAGNI principle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a regex like this:

```
http:\/\/(.*?)[.?]|http:\/\/
```

Instead of performing multiple replaces.  This would catch any other sub-domains you encounter.  I'm not aware of another way you can achieve this.

This is actually not as short as it could be but I wanted to keep it readable.

Comment: Don't forget to adjust this for HTTPS etc.