# How to get website name from domain name?

Tags: c#, uri

I fetch the domain from the URL as follows:

```
var uri = new Uri("Http://www.google.com");
var host = uri.Host;
//host ="www.google.com"
```

But I want only google.com in Host,

```
host = "google.com"
```

Comment: You can do it manually

Comment: But what about URL's where the subdomain is not "www".  Do you want to keep or discard it?  For example, "espn.go.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `host` begins with `"www."`, you can replace `"www."` with an empty string using [String.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("Http://www.google.com");
var host = uri.Host.ToLower();
if (host.StartsWith("www."))
{
    host = host.Replace("www.", "");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the accepted answer I guess the issue was not knowing how to manipulate strings rather than how to deal with uris... but for anyone else who ends up here:

The Uri class does not have this property so you will have to parse it yourself.

Presumably you do not know what the subdomain is before time so a simple replace may not be possible.

This is not trivial since the TLDs are so varied (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), and there maybe be multiple parts to the url (eg http://pre.subdomain.domain.co.uk).

You will have to decide exactly what you want to get and how complex you want the solution to be.

simple - do a string replace, see ekad's answer

medium - regex that works most of the time, see [Strip protocol and subdomain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644051/strip-protocol-and-subdomain-from-a-url)

or complex - refer to a list of suffixes in order to figure out what is subdomain and what is domain eg
[Get the subdomain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url)